# Perl: How to download a large zip file in a loop and provide feedback

Tags: perl

Using Perl, how do I download a large zip file from a web server, and while it's downloading, post status messages? I tried [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple)'s `getstore()` and turned on [`$ua->show_progress(1)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-show_progress), but it hangs while it's downloading and I can't provide feedback over POSIX Named Pipes to another application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw($ua getstore);
use POSIX qw(WNOHANG);

my $sURL = "http://example.com/example.zip";
my $sSaveFile = "/tmp/download.zip";

# it's probably a good idea to first check the server with a HEAD request on the URL before wasting time on a download. 
# But, besides that, here you go...

my $sMessage = "Downloading";
my $pid = fork(); 
if ($pid == 0) {
  getstore($sURL,$sSaveFile);
  exit;
}
do {
    # here, I print, but you could also provide feedback via Named Pipes or some other mechanism
    # you might also want to do a byte check to see if the file size is increasing, and if not, increase a flag counter, and if you hit like 5 flags, give up on the download with a "last" statement.
    # remember, byte checks can easily be done with: my $nBytes = (-s $sSaveFile);
    print "$sMessage\n";
    $sMessage .= '.';
    sleep(2);
} while (waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)==0);
print "\n\nDONE\n\n";
```

I found I had to do it this way instead of shelling out and running curl because on OSX Lion, it has a bug with Curl timing out after 30 seconds when used in a piped process, while versions of OSX after that no longer had this bug.

Answer (score 1):

After the comments on this answer specified the problems more precisely then your question you might try below. This forks a child with the download and in the master you will be able to read the progress information from a file descriptor.

Nevertheless, a much better interaction between the download and your program which handles the progress might be possible, because in my opinion forking a process just so that the download can somehow displayed is ugly. But this part of the download feedback depends mostly on the way you've designed your progress showing application, and this design is unknown too me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = "http://...";
my $file = "outputfile";

pipe my $rfh, my $wfh;
defined( my $pid = fork() ) or die "fork failed: $!";
if ($pid == 0) {
    # download in child, redirect progress to pipe
    close($rfh);
    $wfh->autoflush(1);
    open(STDERR,">&",$wfh) || die $!;
    close($wfh);

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->show_progress(1);
    $ua->get($url, ':content_file' => $file );
    exit;
}

# read in master from pipe
close($wfh);
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
while (sysread($rfh, my $buf, 8192,0)) {
    print "progress... $buf\n";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this might be a start in the right direction with some finagling, but I don't know how. This approach hangs on the get statement. I can't send a custom Named Pipes progress message back in a loop back to my Objective C app. (I've built a Mac installer in Objective C that forks out to Perl in the background to do its work, and Perl uses named pipes to talk back to the Objective C app so that it can tell it an error on download or update the progress.) Do you know how to alter your answer so that I can loop?

Comment: @Volomike: actually I have no idea what kind of output you expect from the program. It might simply hang because you don't read all the progress information it writes to the output because after a while the pipe gets full and it will block until it can write more data - which needs the other end of the pipe to read the data first.

Comment: I used "hang" in the wrong way. I mean it blocks on that command, and updates output to the screen. What I'd like to do is, after the get statement occurs, instead of sitting right there, it lets me do a do/while loop until that process completes. And, every 2 seconds in that loop, I can send a progress message back to my named pipe. My routine works in the answer I have posted here, but unfortunately it has to shell out to run the Perl interpreter again.

Comment: @Volomike: in the hope that I know understood your problem I've edited the answer. But I recommend that you edit your original question so that it better describes what you were trying to achieve.